# Gripping with radial palms

Tags: biology, xenobiology, bio-mechanics

How would gripping of different objects, such as rocks and sticks, work for an organism that has radially symmetrical hands, resembling starfish in shape.

They have four to five digits, depending on which is the most convenient for gripping various different shapes, spread along the sides of their palm with equal spacing between them.

Assume jointed digits like those of a human, but you know, radial.

Edit: Additional pondering, how would grip-strength be affected by such a setup?

Comment: Try it with three: Thumb, index, little. See how well you can hold a spoon.

Comment: If our hands only had those three fingers, we wouldn't have ever created spoons in the way we currently have.  Instead, we would probably have a tennis ball shape on the handle so we could easily hold it.

Comment: «Try it with three: Thumb, index, little. See how well you can hold a spoon.» This is a good idea, but I found it crippling, much like trying to draw with my toes. My hand just wasn't built to work that way. Instead, I took both hands and pushed them together at the wrists, then tucked my ring and pinkie fingers into the middle, sandwiching them between my palms. I used my thumbs together as one digit, and my four remaining fingers individually. If you like, try this. Now try to manipulate things. You still have the maneuverability of the dominant three digits that you would use t

Comment: From a purely structural viewpoint they'd have to have fairly strange hands. Human finger strength is actually transmitted via tendons from muscles in the forearm. To have the same setup with a radial hand would require either tendons spreading radially from the centre of the hand (and hence housed inside the bones of the forearm) or tendons that wrap around the palm (and hence cross one another). Weird, but not unimaginable!

Answer (score 7):

Round objects would be preferred. They'd probably hold cups from the bottom. That would change how their things would be designed more than anything else. They'd like things like stick shifts and levers with knobs more than, say, a steering wheel.

I don't think they'd have too much issue with picking up things. Simply, instead of using all their fingers, they'd only use a few. Go ahead and pick up your pencil with just your thumb and pinkie fingers. Fairly easy and straightforward. This would be how they would grip "Irregular" objects. If a finger can't wrap around it, just put it out of the way.

Manipulating objects would also be done with limited numbers of fingers. You don't necessarily need to *grip* everything.